# create new column from if else statement

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe named data with variable salary with ranges

```
SALARY:0 1 2 3 ...  1000
```

i want to bucket the salary variable and create a new variable salary band. where if salary= 0 that is missing band, 1-200 that is low, 200-800 that is mid and above 800 is high.

```
data['SALARY_BAND'] = np.where(data['SALARY']<=0, 'Missing', 
                             np.where(data['SALARY'] <=200, 'low'),
                              np.where(data['SALARY'] <800, 'mid','high' ))
```

when i run i get error  value missing y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
data['SALARY_BAND'] = np.where(data['SALARY']<=0, 'Missing', 
                        np.where(data['SALARY'] <=200, 'low',
                          np.where(data['SALARY'] <800, 'mid','high' )))
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use the `cut` function:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(range(0, 1001, 10)), columns=['SALARY'])
df['SALARY_BAND'] = pd.cut(df.SALARY,
                           [-1, 0, 200, 800, df.SALARY.max()],
                           labels=['Missing', 'low', 'mid', 'high'])
```